# http with Observable in Angular 2 cant use data

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable, angular-cli

i am new to angular 2 and to observables but i wanted to give it a shot. So i have installed the angular-cli and made a simple test project.

All i wanted it to do is read a json file and work with the data inside of a component (the first intention was to make a service but i wanted to start on a low basis).

So i have created a json file in the assets/json folder (testjson.json):

```
{
  "teststring": "test works"
}
```

then i have imported the http from angular and the rxjs map stuff inside of my content.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string = "Default";
  data;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    http.get('assets/json/testjson.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {this.data = data; this.title = data.teststring; console.log(this.data);});
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

So far so good, the app prints out the following:

```
app works!

test works [object Object]
```

But i want to use this data in the whole component, not only in the constructor. but if i try to console.log "this.data" outside of the constructor (inside the ngOnInit function), it prints undefined in the console.

I know, that it must have something to do with asynch loading but unfortunately i have no clue how to tell the app to wait until this.data is filled.

I hope you can help me with that. Of course in the future i want a service which does that kind of stuff and more than one component should grab data from it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First move your async code from constructor to ngOnInit(). Your data is available after promise is resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You should move the initialization code to the initialization method.
- Your data becomes available once the callback completes. In your template you can use `*ngIf` to execute code inside a block once there is data. As long as the `*ngIf` does not eval to true the inner code will not run.
- The only way you can run `console.log(data)` is  from inside the callback or called from the callback because you have to wait until the data is loaded.

**content.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="data">
  <span>{{data.teststring}}</span>
</div>
```

**content.component.ts**

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string = "Default";
  data: any = null;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/json/testjson.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.title = data.teststring;
        console.log(this.data);
      });
  }
}
```

---

### Edit

*In response to the comment below* If you abstract out the http call to a service you can see the exact same logic still applies. You are still using the concept of a promise of data and that you can subscribe to that promise once it has completed. The only difference here is the http call is abstracted to a different class.

**content.component.ts**

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string = "Default";
  data: any = null;

  // inject service
  constructor(private contentService:ContentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contentService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.title = data.teststring;
        console.log(this.data);
      });
  }
```

**Service**

```
export class ContentService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getData(): IObservable<{teststring:string}> { // where string can be some defined type
    return http.get('assets/json/testjson.json')
      .map(res => res.json() as {teststring:string});
  }
```

Comment: ok thanks but console.log is just to quickly test if data is there. imagine i have a service, holding this.data and i want to call a getter of the service from a component to get that data and print teststring out. As long as the async request is running the getter will not be able to deliver the right data. so if i call the getter inside of the component the service will deliver undefined. how can i wait for the service to have this.data filled?

Comment: @sonnenpriester - the exact same way you do now. You return an IObservable from your service which has the promise of data and subscribe to it from your component. The only difference between the code above and adding a service is abstracting the `http` call to the service.

Comment: @sonnenpriester - I added another example with a service. As you can see the concept does not change, you work with promises of doing something and then subscribe to that promise to execute something when the promise has completed.

Comment: would that mean, that we have a request for every component that gets data from the service? My intention was that the service makes one request and stores data in this.data and all components just call a getter to get the data stored in this.data from the service.

Comment: @sonnenpriester - you could cache the data result in the service as a variable. The component then checks for the existence of the data in the service and if it has not yet been initialized call the method in the same way the code is written above.