# How to display results after fetching JSON from external source in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, object, jsonp, observable

I'm making a simple search engine for movie data using omdbapi.com API. I've set up the service to fetch the data and the components to create the view but when I try to connect to the HTML i get an error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
>   Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Movie class

```
export class Movie {
    constructor(
        Title: string,
        Year: string,
        Rated: string,
        Released: string,
        Runtime: string,
        Genre: string,
        Director: string,
        Writer: string,
        Actors: string,
        Plot: string,
        Language: string,
        Country: string,
        Awards: string,
        Poster: string,
        Metascore: string,
        imdbRating: string,
        imdbVotes: string,
        imdbID: string,
        Type: string,
        Response: string
    ) {}

}
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

//observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

import { MovieSearchService } from './movie-search.service';
import { Movie } from './movie';

@Component({
    selector: 'movie-search',
    templateUrl: './movie-search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./movie-search.component.css'],
    providers: [MovieSearchService]
})

export class MovieSearchComponent implements OnInit {
    movies: Observable<Movie[]>;
    private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(
        private movieSearchService: MovieSearchService,
        private http: Http
    ) {}

    search(term:string) {
        return this.searchTerms.next(term);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.movies = this.searchTerms
        .debounceTime(300) // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
        .distinctUntilChanged() // ignore if next search term is same as previous
        .switchMap(term => term // switch to new observable each time the term changes
        // return the http search observable
        ? this.movieSearchService.search(term)
            // or the observable of empty heroes if there was no search term
        : Observable.of<Movie[]>([])
        )
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("--------- Error -------");
            console.log( error );

            return Observable.of<Movie[]>([]);
        })     
    }
}
```

This is the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Movie } from './movie';

@Injectable()
export class MovieSearchService {
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private jsonp: Jsonp
    ) {}

    search(term: string): Observable<Movie[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${term}`)
            .map(response => {
                return response.json().each() as Movie[]
            })
    }
}
```

And the view

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <input #searchBox id="search-box" />
   <button (click)="search(searchBox.value)">Search</button>
</div>

<ul *ngIf="movies">
    <li *ngFor="let movie of movies">
        {{ movie.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

How may I make the view show the movie title for each movie?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http with Observable in Angular 2 cant use data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961693/http-with-observable-in-angular-2-cant-use-data)

Comment: Please post a sample of the JSON structure returned from the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check the network tab to see if you are actually receiving data and how that data looks like.

Testing this. Apparently you first of all need to build your url like this:

```
return this.http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+term)
```

Then as to the response, it's built like this:

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"24","Year":"2001–2010","imdbID"....
```

So what you need to extract to get an array:

```
.map(response => {response.json().Search})
```

and subscribe in your component:

```
this.movieSearchService.search(term)
  .subscribe(d => this.movies = d)
```

and then when you want to display your title:

```
<ul *ngIf="movies">
    <li *ngFor="let movie of movies">
        {{ movie.Title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice the `Search` and `Title` in the above codes. This is case sensitive, so you need to e.g use  `{{ movie.Title }}` with a capital `T` to be able to display your data.

This should clear things up! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AJT_82

Comment: You are welcome! :) as said, use your developer tools, e.g in chrome by F12. Then open your network tab and check the request and seeing if you get a response at all. With your url there was empty response and that's why you couldn't iterate. Here's a pic. Check the parts where I marked yellow :) http://imgur.com/a/RuClo

Comment: Sorry, this posted my answer accidentally before I finished. I am getting an error:

<pre>Argument of type '(term: string) => Subscription | Observable<Movie[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
Type 'Subscription | Observable<Movie[]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
 </pre>

I believe this is  because I declare movies as an observable object such as movies: Observable<Movie[]>
Movie contains the structure (title, year, etc...)

If I don't declare it as Observable, how should I declare the variable movies?

Comment: Do you have a `Movie` interface or class? If not, you could create one. But it will also work as declaring the array as `any`. `movies: any[] = []` But I'd suggest you create an interface. This is though not necessary, as it has no effect on runtime. But if not for anything else, it's supports coding. Both compiler and the developer himself/herself :)

Comment: Yes, I have a movie class. I've updated the code with the Movie class. 
If I don't use any[] = [] ,  what is the correct path to go from here?

Comment: Since you have a class, you can declare it as an array of type movie, so: `movies: Movie[] = []`

Comment: Thank you very much @AJT_82
I was trying to apply what I learned from the Angular2 Tour of heroes tutorial but seems like there are simpler and easier ways to do the same thing. Kudos to you :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help! :) Well there are a couple of things you can use. The TOH are using Promises and Observables+async pipe if I remember correctly. Personally I like to use subscribe myself instead of the async pipe (which does the subscription for you).